# Reading blob from database without saving to disk in Python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to read a set of records from db which has a blob field. I am able to read it but not without saving it to disk first.

```
cursor.execute("select image ,id, 
department from dept_master")
depdata = cursor.fetchall()
for row in depdata:
    file_like = io.BytesIO(row[0])
    file = PIL.Image.open(file_like)
    target = os.path.join("/path-to-save/", 'folder-save')
    destination = "/".join([target, file.filename])
    file.save(destination)
```

How can I read it and display it without first saving to disk ?

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something... Presumably there's another route which then serves that saved file from the filesystem?  And you want to know how to serve the file immediately in this route?  Perhaps edit question to make this more clear.

Comment: @v25  I am not sure what is not clear here. I want to read and display the blob data directly after fetching it from db.

Comment: How do you wish to display this.  The question is tagged flask, so are you looking to use the `send_file` function to get this to the frontend?  This isn't mentioned.

Comment: I am planning to use render_template to display the data

Answer (score 0):

> I am planning to use render_template to display the data

To serve the images from a blob field, you need to create a separate route which serves the actual image data specifically, then in a template include links which load the files from this route.

There's no need to use PIL here, as the blob field gives you bytes data.  You run that through BytesIO to get a `_io.BytesIO` object, which can be passed straight to Flask's `send_file` function.

```
from io import BytesIO
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/image/<int:ident>')
def image_route(ident):

    # This can only serve one image at a time, so match by id
    cursor.execute("select image from dept_master WHERE id = ?", (ident,)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    image_bytes = result[0]

    bytes_io = BytesIO(image_bytes)

    return send_file(bytes_io, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

At this stage you should be able to hit `/image/1` and see the image in your browser for the row with id `1`.

Then, somewhere in a template, just include the link for this with:

```
<img src='{{ url_for("image_route", ident=image_ident) }}' />
```

This assumes that `image_ident` is available in the template.  You might need to replace this variable name with something which exsists (could be a variable within a for loop which denotes the image id to pull).

Let me know if this needs further explaining.

Comment: Thanks for your code. Working fine.  Instead of fetchone can we have all images displayed in a tabular format using fetchall?

Comment: @John this type of thing should probably be implemented in the other route which renders the 'gallery' template.  You'll still need a single request for every image, as flask's `send_file` function can only send a single file at once, hence the use of `fetchone` in the `image_route` function.