# Flask pass image from sqlite blob to template

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite, flask

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTy8O.png)I have a database that stores images in one of the columns, they are store as a BLOB, this is how im saving it:

```
with open("download.png", 'rb') as file:
    data = file.read()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ", (value_list))
```

this is how im retrieving it:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")
my_list = cursor.fetchall()
DDBB.close()
```

this is how im passing it:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    posts = get_posts()

    return render_template("index.html", my_list=posts)
```

this is what im using it for:

```
{% for item in my_list %}
<div class="col-4 text-center mt-5">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ item[0] }}" id="imgslot" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="mb-1">Name: {{ item[2] }}</p>
            <p class="mb-1">Location: {{ item[1] }}</p>
            <p class="mb-2">{{ item[3] }}</p>
            <p class="mb-2">Posted by: {{ item[4] }}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
{% endfor %}
```

the card is reading everything correctly, but the image is not loading, using the inspect of chrome seems like the value is the passing incorrectly.

Can anyone please help me understand this better (im new to flask and have no html experience)

Comment: I think this may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61061587/2052575 You'll probaby need to build an individual route which does something like `SELECT image_blob FROM table WHERE id = ?` then serves that image.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, showing the information added to the database and the path obtained in inspect element would help understand the error better. Make sure you are passing the path correctly. Try this out : https://pynative.com/python-mysql-blob-insert-retrieve-file-image-as-a-blob-in-mysql/

You can save the images in a static folder and then obtain it from there by using

```html
<img id="imgID" src="{{ url_for('static',filename=image_name) }}">
```

Comment: added image with the inspect of the element

Comment: Try this out: https://pynative.com/python-mysql-blob-insert-retrieve-file-image-as-a-blob-in-mysql/ ... I know you are looking for sqlite but the syntax is similar

Comment: im trying to save it on a variable then pass it over, that way i dont have to create x amount of images, every time the page is open(this is part of the index, yet i am dinamically locating the card into the page, so it show all the entries of the part of the database)

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in way of reading the values:

```
for y in range(len(my_list)):
        rec_data=my_list[y][0]

        with open('static/img/post/img'+str(y)+'.jpg','wb') as f:
            f.write(rec_data)
```