# Render Blob from sqlite server in HTML with Flask/Python

Tags: python, html, blob

This piece of code renders an html template with values from my db

```
        displayrows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE profile_id = :profile_id", (session["user_id"],))
        displayrows = db.fetchall()
        displaycount = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bucketlist WHERE wish_id = :wish_id", (session["user_id"],))
        for i in displayrows:
            bytes_io = BytesIO(i[5])
        for i in displaycount:
            return render_template("profile.html", rows = displayrows, count = i[0], image = bytes_io)
```

This is part of the html page which renders the values...

```
<div class="card bg-dark" style="width: 18rem;">
    <p class="list-group-item">BucketList Size - {{ count }}</p>
    {%for row in rows%}
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">  
            <li class="list-group-item">Location - {{ row[1] }}, {{row[2]}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Looking for - {{row[3] }}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Bio - {{row[4]}}</li>
        </ul>  
    {%endfor%}
         <img src="{{image}}" />
</div>
```

I'm very new to python, flask, and coding in general so I would appreciate it if anybody takes time to explain how I can successfully display data from the blob column on an html page. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd skip trying to b64 encode this, and instead set up a separate endpoint that serves a single image, based on a provided ID.  I [answered a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61061587/2052575). If that doesn't help you, can you please include how you computed `displayrows` (ie. The SQL query) and I can write an answer taylored to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I removed the PIL code and implemented your solution in the link, I also passed a variable to my template, it however returns the address of the byte object like this ```<_io.BytesIO object at 0x1071a83b0>```, I don't understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

- You can't have a return statement within a for loop.  The view function can only return once.
- You need one route to render the profile page, and another to return the image.

I think I'm making some assumptions on what you're trying to do here, but hopefully this makes sense...

---

Have one route that renders the profile page:

```
@app.route('/profile')
def profile():

    # You could pull several profiles here, but as you provide an id it just pulls one:
    db.execute("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE profile_id = ?", (session["user_id"],))

    # Again, this supports multiple had the query been `SELECT * FROM profiles`
    displayrows = db.fetchall()
    
    return render_template("profile.html", rows = displayrows)
```

Then in the template `profile.html`, within the for loop use flask's `url_for` function to generate a link to the image, passing `row[0]` (which should be that profile's id) as the `ident` argument:

```
{% for row in rows %}
        ...
        <img src='{{ url_for("profile_image", ident = row[0]) }}' />
        ...
{% endfor %}
```

That `url_for` function will output the correct hyperlink for the next route. Notice how this accepts the `ident` which is the profile id.  You'll need to replace `your_blob_col` with the column title which holds the bolb:

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/i/<int:ident>')
def profile_image(ident):
    db.execute("SELECT your_blob_col FROM profiles WHERE profile_id = ?", (ident,))
    result = db.fetchone() # There's only one
    image_bytes = result[0] # The first and only column

    bytes_io = BytesIO(image_bytes)

    return send_file(bytes_io, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

So the hyperlink in the `<img>` tag would render as something like `/i/123` which when handled by the `profile_image` function will return the image data.

You can inspect these requests in your browser's dev tools (Network tab) for a better understanding of what's going on.  If your `profile` function had instead pulled `n` profiles, you'd be looking at 1 request for the `profile` route, and `n` requests to the `profile_image` route.

Let me know if any of this isn't clear :)